# Copy all files on cron run - regular task

Tags: cron, rsync, file-copying

I've got a virtual dedicated server (running FreeBSD 6.x) and I need to regulary backup files from one folder to another, say from */home/LOGIN/data/www/mydomain.com/test1* to */home/LOGIN/data/www/mydomain.com/test2*. I've tried different approaches:

```
rsync -a /home/LOGIN/data/www/mydomain.com/test1 /home/LOGIN/data/www/mydomain.com/test2
cp /home/LOGIN/data/www/mydomain.com/test1 /home/LOGIN/data/www/mydomain.com/test2
cp www/mydomain.com/test1 /www/mydomain.com/test2
```

but all this didn't work, it gave error #127 and others.

AFAIK this can be done using a php script to run by cron also.

what is the better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

> cp /home/LOGIN/data/www/mydomain.com/test1/*
>   /home/LOGON/data/www/mydomain.com/test2

and make sure the test2 directory is existent

Comment: sorry, my fault. The -a option of cp isn't existing in FreeeBSD 6.x, it was introduced in FreeBSD 7.x. Please try again without the -a switch (I've edited my answer). -a stands for archive mode (preserving attributes, recursive copy). After your copy session is generally working, there is time to think about the really needed switches for the cp command.